# Activation and Deployment of `QVirtualKeyboard` (in Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

How do I activate the Qt5 virtual keyboard for my application?
And more importantly, what files are needed for the Qt virtual keyboard to appear in my deployed application?

Im asking this Q&A style since it's taken me surprisingly long to put together all bits and pieces. Maybe someone else will benefit from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for Qt Virtual Keyboard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html) is actually not that bad. However putting everything in place for a deployed application is still challenging for `QtWidgets/C++` projects. I've tested following suggestions with Qt 5.10 and Windows 10:

1. Install the virtual keyboard. In Windows this is possible with the Qt installer, by selecting the option "Qt Virtual Keyboard" under the respective Qt version.

   (Tell me what's needed for other platforms - I'll add this information)
2. [Enable the environment variable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-deployment-guide.html#loading-the-plugin), i.e. loading the plugin can be implemented in the `main.cpp` (before instantiating any `QApplication`):

   ```
   qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
   ```

   This will enable the virtual keyboard for any input field.
3. What files are needed for the deployment of an application? The virtual keyboard needs its own plugin.dll, and it depends on the modules `Qt5Network, QtQml, QtQuick, QtSvg`. So the directory structure would have to have at least these files:

   ```
   platforminputcontexts/qtvirtualkeyboardplugin.dll
   YOURBIN.exe
   Qt5Network.dll
   Qt5Qml.dll
   Qt5Quick.dll
   Qt5Svg.dll
   ```

   **Edit:** The plugin will dynamically load some more plugins, also using plugin description files, so deploy these, too (find them in the `qml` sub-dir of the qt installation directory):

   ```
   Qt/labs/folderlistmodel/qmldir
   Qt/labs/folderlistmodel/qmlfolderlistmodelplugin.dll
   QtQuick/Layouts/qmldir
   QtQuick/Layouts/qquicklayoutsplugin.dll
   QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/Styles/qmldir
   QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/Styles/qtvirtualkeyboardstylesplugin.dll
   QtQuick/Window.2/qmldir
   QtQuick/Window.2/windowplugin.dll
   QtQuick.2/qmldir
   QtQuick.2/qtquick2plugin.dll
   ```
4. Apart from these files, the standard Dlls are needed and possibly other plugins, DLLs. This all depends on your configuration and also if you use MSVC or MinGW:

   ```
   iconengines/...dll
   imageformats/...dll
   platform/...dll
   Qt5Gui.dll
   Qt5Widget.dll
   Qt5Core.dll
   libwinpthread-1.dll
   libEGL.dll
   libGLESv2.dll
   libstdc++-6.dll
   libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
   ```

**Note:** The [qt windows deployment tool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) is a nice and handy tool. However, it did not, by default, copy all files required for the virtual keyboard.

**EDIT - Note2:** The [qt windows deployment tool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) can copy *almost* all required files. It won't copy the virtual keyboard style DLL (Qt 5.10, Mingw). Also it does copy a lot of unnecessary files, if only virtual keyboard is required:

```
windeployqt.exe --compiler-runtime --qmldir c:\Qt\5.10.0\mingw53_32\qml 
--quick --qml --release --force PATH_TO_BINARY
```

Then manually create the directories/copy the respective DLL + `qmldir` from and to:

```
QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/Styles
```